# JavaScript: Link 2 Div's with Horizontal Scroll on IE5

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, scroll

I have the below javascript that takes 2 different div's as an argument. It pretty much just puts a scroll function on the header div and attaches it to the body. This works perfectly fine in most browsers but IE is giving me a headache. My corporate policy forces us to use IE5 and this doesn't work. I tried switching the 3rd line in the function to use event.target instead of event.srcElement and the last line to use body.attachEvent(...) instead of body.addEventListener(...) but no luck with those.

```
function linkDivs(headingDivName,bodyDivName) {
     heading = document.getElementById(headingDivName);
     body = document.getElementById(bodyDivName);
     heading._syncScroll = function() { heading.scrollLeft = event.srcElement.scrollLeft; };
     heading._scrollSyncDirection = "horizontal";
     heading._syncTo = body;
     body.addEventListener("scroll", heading._syncScroll);
```

}

Any idea if there's anything javascript-wise that can help me out in IE5?

Comment: IE5? Seriously? (from wikipedia "Initial release March 18, 1999; 17 years ago"). I must know what dinosaur of a company you work for.

Comment: Tell me about it, there's a corp. policy that im forced to use due to some reasons I cannot explain here. But dinosaur for sure lol. I will be deleting this post since I don't think any solution can be found.